# Why am I getting a "C compiler cannot create executables" (successfully written C code prior to this and compiles that)?

Tags: ruby, osx-lion

This is the error I am getting when typing ./configure :

```
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/opt/ruby-1.9.3-p125':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

As is obvious by above, I am trying to compile the Ruby source code. I did some research but doesn't look like anybody has attempted compiling the code themselves on Lion. I am currently running 10.7.3 OS X Lion, Macbook Pro.

Comment: Do you have a the [developer tools](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) installed?

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but what does the `config.log` say?

Comment: Yes, the latest Xcode. I have compiled C programs before no problem, its just compiling source code. Its my first time and I am trying to learn.

Comment: @owlstead not stupid, I think its more stupid that I don't know how to access it?

Comment: Try mipadi's advice first, then look for it. If you find it, open it in a plain text editor. If you cannot find it one of the geniusses here will probably know where it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Xcode 4.3+, did you install the command-line tools? You can download them from within Xcode's preference pane, or from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

Comment: hmm, I am not sure if I have the command line tools installed. I will check. How can I test whether I do or not?

Comment: Looking, but I see nothing that allows me to download it or if I even have it.

Comment: 4.2 I just looked around and it is not the latest, but would getting the command line tools matter that much in an update?

Comment: @Andy: Xcode 4.3+ is bundled differently. If you have 4.2, there's an option to install command-line tools when you run the installer.

Comment: Downloading it now. Since we are on the subject of Xcode, each bundle is installed and kept on my mac. Feel like its a waste of space. Should I delete the older versions? And it seems Lion also changed the directory structure of Xcode. Any idea why?

Comment: @Andy: Xcode 4.3 is packaged as a `.app`, making it easier to distribute and update through the App Store. Once installed, you can safely delete `/Developer`.