# RVM Ruby install Issue

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am trying to install Ruby 1.9.3 via RVM. However, I keep getting the error in the attached picture. [image: Error Message]

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: These are not errors, but only instruction.

Comment: Please don't use a picture to illustrate what is really a text message. Copy the message into your question, format it correctly, and it can be indexed by Google, Yahoo, and other engines, allowing other people to find your question and any answers.

Answer (score 3):

What you see isn't an error, it's what you should read to understand what you now need to do to configure your environment to install rubies.

Comment: jut a note - use keyboard arrows to navigate!

Answer (score 2):

Not errors; just instructions. Basically, RVM is telling you that Ruby 1.9.3 has dependencies that you need to install before proceeding. Those dependencies can be installed with a package manager such as aptitude (Linux Ubuntu) or Homebrew (Mac).

In your case, you will need Homebrew since you are on the mac.

If you do not yet have homebrew, please go [here](https://brew.sh/) to install it. Once it is installed, please install the missing dependencies. In your case:

```
$ brew install libksba
```

Now, proceed with installing Ruby 1.9.3:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3 # install 1.9.3 
$ rvm use 1.9.3 --default # makes ruby 1.9.3 the default
```

Please feel free to post in the comments if you need more help.

Comment: Hi Sybohy, thanks for the quick response. I have ran the 'brew install libksba' command & it tells me that "libksba-1.2.0 already installed". But when I run 'rvm install 1.9.3' it gives me the message I posted in the picture above. Any thoughts on how to resolve?

Comment: In that case, you are probably ready to go. Use arrows to move down the message notice. It should indicate which key to press to continue and proceed with the install. For example, on Ubuntu, pressing 'q' will dismiss the message and begin the installation.