# Somehow my installation of Ruby on Mountain Lion got corrupted and now I'm getting a cryptic message from RVM

Tags: ruby, macos, gcc, installation, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby (and eventually Rails) with RVM.
Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/Mayank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374 --with-opt-dir=/Users/Mayank/.rvm/usr --disable-shared', please read /Users/Mayank/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p374/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Here's the configure.log:

```
[2013-01-31 00:13:22] ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking for C compiler default output file name...
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I've run

```
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2
```

and verified that there is a gcc-4.2 there.

RVM always gets to the "configuring" stage and then seems to go into a loop with bash and env alternatingly showing up on the top of the terminal window.

I tried rerunning RailsInstaller, but that didn't do anything.

This all started because

```
heroku db:push
```

wasn't supported with 1.9.3 and 1.9.2 wasn't installing.

I don't even know how to search for an error like this, but I've tried everything that worked for others.

edit. I just ran **rvm debug** and got this:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p374:
/Users/Mayank/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /Users/Mayank/.rvm/bin/ruby: Argument list too long
/Users/Mayank/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /Users/Mayank/.rvm/bin/ruby: Undefined error: 0
```

Comment: List config.log file contents here please. Nearest suggestion -- it misnames compiler (like ``gcc`` instead of ``gcc-4.2``, etc).

Comment: Where can I find config.log?

Comment: In on of the subfolders in your build folder (where you are running configure from).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error installing Ruby with RVM (OSX 10.8)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072524/error-installing-ruby-with-rvm-osx-10-8)

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug in railisinstaller, update RVM `rvm get head` and read the output, more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14078475/497756

Answer (score 0):

Below code works!

```
Minis-MacBook-Air:website daraotsu$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
Minis-MacBook-Air:website daraotsu$ rvm use 2.1.1
Using /Users/daraotsu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1
Minis-MacBook-Air:website daraotsu$ rails s
```