# Error at the end of Installation of Ruby 2.0.0 on Mac Mountain Lion, also no mysql.sock file

Tags: ruby, macos

I am a total noob to Ruby and Rails, so any help is appreciated about this.

I installed Ruby 2.0.0 using RVM. It got most of the way through, when I got this error message:

`Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/Users/victoriamielke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/Users/victoriamielke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global:/Users/victoriamielke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/Users/victoriamielke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global GEM_HOME=/Users/victoriamielke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0 /Users/victoriamielke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby -d /Users/victoriamielke/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.3/setup.rb --verbose',
please read /Users/victoriamielke/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rubygems.install.log
Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.`

I also opened up rubygems.install.log, and it said near the end:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `fu_stream_blksize' for #<Gem::Commands::SetupCommand:0x007fcab29f5838>
```

What caused the failure of Rubygems to install?

Another problem am having is the error message ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2). I tried a Google search on this, which said I needed to find the mysql.sock file. Well, I have never found this file on my computer and could not find out in plain English how to add it or generate it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the installation error is a recent [**known issue**](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1712). If you're a beginner I recommend using Ruby 1.9.3, since 2.0.0 is brand new and you'll certainly find bugs in both the language implementation *and* libraries that haven't been tested on 2.0.0 yet.

The second issue is unrelated. It could be that you haven't started MySQL (did you run `mysql.server start`?), file permissions, MySQL configuration, or any number of other issues. You're not supposed to create `/tmp/mysql.sock` yourself, it's created automatically by MySQL. Please open a separate question about it.

Comment: I tried to install 1.9.3, and I got this error message at the end:

Comment: With my attempt to install 1.9.3, got this message: 
apple-gcc42 is not available in PATH, try:

    brew unlink apple-gcc42 && brew link apple-gcc42

and make sure that apple-gcc42 is available in your PATH:

    which gcc-4.2

Comment: I decided to do a clean install of Mac OSX. Installed Xcode with command line tools, git, homebrew, rvm. Tried to install 1.9.3 again and got:Error running 'make', please read /Users/victoriamielke/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/make.log. Error at the endof the log said: st.c:520:35: error: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'st_index_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Werror,-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            i = table->num_entries++;
              ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~

Comment: Looks like this happens because clang is used by default, but only GCC works (so far). You might try executing `export CC=gcc-4.2` before installing. Here's more info: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/297

Comment: I did finally get it installed with using command as shown at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072524/error-installing-ruby-with-rvm-osx-10-8).

Comment: I'm glad your persistance was rewarded! I think you should post that link as an answer and accept it, so anyone arriving at this question from Google can quickly identify the fix.

Comment: I tried to use the mini Markdown, and it didn't seem to display right. I'm a newbie at everything. The link was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072524/error-installing-ruby-with-rvm-osx-10-8